# Trouble in proving that $\|x\|_p = \max|x_j|$

Tags: proof-writing, normed-spaces

We define p-norm in this way: $\|x\|_p = \{\sum ^N_j=_1|x_j|^p\}^ {1\over p}$
We know that It change to $\|x\|_p = \max|x_j| $    when $ p \to \infty $
 How can I prove this ?

Comment: Hint: Chebyshev's inequality

Comment: I don't know really  Chebyshev's inequality.no idea plz help me more! I could prove that $||x||_p$ Is smaller than $ Max|x_j| + 1$ with Triangle_inequality but I want more!

Comment: This question is an infinite-dimensional version of this: [The $ l^{\infty} $-norm is equal to the limit of the $ l^{p} $-norms.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we have to prove is that if $x_1,\dots,x_K$ are real numbers such that $0\leqslant x_k\lt 1$, then 
$$\lim_{p\to \infty}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^Kx_k^p\right)^{1/p}=1.$$
It's equivalent to show that 
$$\lim_{p\to \infty}\frac 1p\log\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^Kx_k^p\right)=0.$$
It's the case, since for $t\geqslant 0$, $0\leqslant\log(1+t)\leqslant t$.

Comment: Giraudo thx for your attention .but I can't understand something in your proof.why $ x_k $ should be $0 \le x_k \lt 1$

Comment: Assume that the maximum of the $|x_j|$ is reached on the first coordinate. So the $p$-norm is $|x_1|$ times a term like in the first displayed equation of the answer.