# How to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[a^n+b^n+c^n\right]^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\left[a^n+b^n+c^n\right]^{1/n}$, assuming that $0<a<b<c$?

I think that, as 1/n tends to zero, the limit 1. Is this correct?

Comment: assuming that what？

Comment: @assume a,b,c > 0?

Comment: ... assuming that $0\le a\le b\le c$, the answer would be $c$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/326172/321264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:
Assuming that $0\le a\le b\le c$, then

$$(c^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le(a^n+b^n+c^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le(3c^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Now let $n\to\infty$,...

Comment: the limit is 3c?

Comment: Assuming that 0≤a≤b≤c,

Comment: the limit is c。

Comment: @Marta: You need to use Squeeze theorem too... and the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{3^{\frac{1}{n}}}=1$