# Limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (A_1^n + ... A_k^n)^{1/n}= \max\{ A_1, ..., A_k\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, radicals

I have the following question. I was asked to compute the following limit: Let $A_1 ... A_k$ be positive numbers, does exist:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (A_1^n + ... A_k^n)^{1/n} $$
My work:
W.L.O.G let $A_1= \max{ A_1, ..., A_k}$, so I have
$$ A_1^n \leq A_1^n + ... A_k^n \leq kA_1^n $$
so that

$$ A_1 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (A_1^n)^{1/n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(A_1^n + ... A_k^n)^{1/n}  \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (kA_1^n)^{1/n}    = kA_1 $$

Can I do something else to sandwich the limit?

Comment: I think $lim_{n\to \infty}(kA_1^n)^{1/n}=A_1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a little mistake. Correction:
$$ A_1 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (A_1^n)^{1/n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(A_1^n + ... A_k^n)^{1/n}  \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (kA_1^n)^{1/n}    = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_1{\color{blue}{k^{1/n}}}=A_1     $$

Comment: Gee thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$
(ab_n)^{1/n} = \exp \left(\frac 1n \log b_n + \frac 1n \log a
\right)
$$
has the same limit when $n\to\infty$ (if any) as $b_n^{1/n}$.