# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}$

Tags: limits, radicals

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}$$

Is there there a way to solve this without using $e^{ln(3^n+4^n)}$?

Maybe:
$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{4^n}=4\,\leq\,\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}\,\leq\,\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2\cdot4^n}=4$?

Comment: Yes. The squeeze theorem is useful here.

Comment: Links to some generalizations:
[How to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=\max \{a,b\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111089) (and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1111089)) or  [Convergence of $\sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n}$ (for $x, y > 0$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80340) (and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/80340).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sqrt [ n ]{ 3^{ n }+4^{ n } }  } =4\cdot \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sqrt [ n ]{ \left( \frac { 3 }{ 4 }  \right) ^{ n }+1 }  } =4$$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine, provided you can use that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2}=1
$$
This follows from Bernoulli’s inequality $(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$, whenever $x>-1$ and $n$ is a positive integer, in the form
$$
\sqrt[n]{1+nx}\le 1+x
$$
For $x=1/n$ this reads
$$
\sqrt[n]{2}\le 1+\frac{1}{n}
$$
and therefore, from
$$
1\le\sqrt[n]{2}\le 1+\frac{1}{n}
$$
and the squeeze theorem, you can conclude.

Then your application of the squeeze theorem to
$$
4=\sqrt[n]{4^n}\le\sqrt[n]{3^n+4^n}\le
\sqrt[n]{2\cdot 4^n}=4\sqrt[n]{2}
$$
is good.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}= \text{max}(a,b)$

details : [Limit Computation, Sandwich.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996983/limit-computation-sandwich)

Comment: I think it is better to add few steps to show how you obtain this answer. Otherwise it is not helpful.

Comment: @Nil : linked to details, couldn't find the equivalent one for min.