# To evaluate a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to evaluate the limit as $x\to0$ of

$$\biggl(\,\sum_{r=1}^{r=n}r^{1/\sin^2x}\biggr)^{\!\sin^{2}x}$$

Comment: Any thoughts on how to approach this problem?  Evidently $n$ is to be some *fixed* positive integer.  Start by considering $n=1$ if you need a concrete case to suggest approaches.

Answer (score 5):

Let $p=\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$. As $x\to 0^+$, $p\to +\infty$, and:
$$ \left(\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^p\right)^{1/p}=\|(1,2,\ldots,n)\|_p \to \max(1,2,\ldots,n)=n.$$

Comment: Is it trivial to show that the limit of the $L_p$ norms as $p\to\infty$ is the $L_\infty$ norm?

Comment: @Braindead: not exactly trivial but well-known, for sure.

Comment: Found the proof :P http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms