# Limit of the nth root of certain averages

Tags: real-analysis

For a positive real numbers $a_1, a_2,.... a_p$ what is

$ \lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{ (a_1^n+a_2^n+....+a_p^n)}{p})^\frac{1}{n}$

Now I apply Cauchy root test on this and i evaluated $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ it comes out

$ \lim_{n\to \infty}$ $ \frac{(a_1^{n+1}+a_2^{n+1}+....+a_p^{n+1})}{(a_1^{n}+a_2^{n}+....+a_p^{n}})$.

then i apply L hospital rule?

Am i right?

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms

Comment: What is Cauchy root test and why are you looking at $a_{n+1}/a_n?$

Comment: i mean cauchy second theorem on limits accoring to which $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n)^\frac{1}{n}= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing, but it doesn't look promising to me. Here's a hint: Let $M= \max(a_1,\dots , a_p).$ Then

$$M^n \le \sum_{k=1}^{p} a_k^n \le pM^n.$$

Comment: then answer is $M$?

Comment: Yes it is. $\,\,$