# Why do we denote the sequence space as $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is really simple. I didn't understand the call the sequence space as $l^\infty$. I know this is from the $l^p$ spaces denotation but I didn't understand the connection between both.

### $l^p$ space

> Let $p\ge 1$ a fixed real number. By definition , each element in the
>    space $l^p$ is a sequence $x=(x_j)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ of numbers such
>    that $|x_1|^p+|x_2|^p+\ldots$ converges and the metric is defined by
>
> $$d(x,y)=\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_j-y_j|^p\bigg)^{1/p}$$

### $l^{\infty}$ space

> Let $X$ be a set of all bounded sequences of complex numbers; that is,
>    every element of $X$ is a complex sequence $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ such
>    for all $j=1,2\ldots$ we have $|x_j|\le c_x$, where $c_x$ is a real
>    number. We choose the metric defined by
>
> $$d(x,y)=sup_{j\in \mathbb N}|x_j-y_j|$$

Comment: Because when $p\to\infty$ the $p$-norm tends to the sup norm.

Comment: @uniquesolution why? this is my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The $ l^{\infty} $-norm is equal to the limit of the $ l^{p} $-norms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms)

Answer (score -1):

We denote it because $$\lim_{p\to\infty} \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty |x_j-y_j|^p\right)^{\frac1p} = \sup_{j\in\mathbb N} |x_j-y_j|$$

Comment: As written, this is clearly false. You want to assume something on the sequences.