# $\ell_\infty$-norm is the supremum of all elements

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\|x\|_p = \|x\|_\infty = \sup_i |x_i|$, where $x$ is a (infinite-dim) sequence. My proof is as follows:

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\|x\|_p = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i|^p)^{1/p}$$
$$=\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \ \sqrt[p]{ |M|^p\times q\times(1+ \sum_{j\neq 1}\frac{(\frac{|x_j|}{|M|})^p}{q}  ) }$$
where I've assumed $|M|$ is the supremum of all $|x_i|$'s (which wlog I've set to $|x_1|$) and $q$ is the number of repetitions of $M$ in $x$.
$$=\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \ |M| \times q^{1/p}\times\sqrt[p]{ (1+ \sum_{j\neq 1}\frac{(\frac{|x_j|}{|M|})^p}{q}  ) }$$
Since $|M|>|x_j|$ for $j\neq 1$, when $p$ goes to infinity $(\frac{|x_j|}{|M|})^p$ goes to zero.

$$=\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} |M|\times q^{1/p}=|M|$$

What am I doing wrong?

I came across the following proof which is far more complicated than mine by a reputable responder. So, I'm guessing I must be doing something wrong.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326266/371990

P.S. I have a guess as to why my solution might not be correct. I think I'm wrongly assuming that $\max \ x_i = \sup \ x_i$ which may not be true in infinite dimensional space.

Comment: Your proof is correct, your statement is wrong. $\|x\|_\infty=\max_{i}|x_i|\not=\max_{i}x_i$. The trivial example would be $x=(-3,-2,0)$. $\|x\|_{\infty}=3$ and not $0$.

Comment: Why have they proved it here with liminf and limsup then? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326266/371990

Comment: The reason is that they prove it for the infinite dimensional space of real-valued sequences.

Comment: @Behrouz Mine is infinite dim as well.

Comment: What if $q\to \infty$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz The limit exists so the sum must be convergent.

Comment: How do you get rid of the sum $$\sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{(\frac{|x_j|}{M})^p}{q}$$ which apears at the end of your computation...? (Note, btw, that the supremum does not need to be attained, i.e. $q$ might be zero.)

Comment: @saz $|M|>|x_j|$ for $j\neq 1$. So when $p$ goes to infinity, $(\frac{|x_j|}{|M|})^p$ goes to zero.

Comment: @saz I also think my prove is wrong because of the implicit assumption that sup is attained.

Comment: For a sequence of infinite sums, just because every term tends to zero, it need not follow that the sequence of sums tends to zero.  You cannot pass a limit through an infinite sum without further justification.

Comment: @Teodorism If it is infinite dimensional case, then your proof needs a lot of detailing: To begin with, you should start with showing $q$ is finite and the sup is achieved which are not that hard (if you assume that $(x_n)\in \ell_p$ for $p\geq p^*$, and also you should take care of the relatively serious comment of Nate Eldredge