# Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{p \longrightarrow \infty} |\cdot|_p = |\cdot|_{\infty}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider $p \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ and the norms $|\cdot|_p, |\cdot|_{\infty}:\mathbb{C}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by, for every $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots,\xi_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$,

$$|\xi|_p=(|\xi_1|^p+|\xi_2|^p+\cdots + |\xi_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
and
$$ |\xi|_{\infty}=\sup_{j \in \{1,\cdots, n\}}|\xi_j|.$$

I want to prove that
$$ \lim_{p \longrightarrow \infty} |\xi|_p = |\xi|_{\infty}.$$

But I have no idea of proceeding, I am not familiar with norms in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms is here answer for you?

Comment: Did you mean $\displaystyle|\xi|_\infty=\text{sup}_{j=1,2,\dots}|\xi_j|$ ?

Comment: Yes. I fixed it.

Comment: @zkutch I guess so. Thanks!

Comment: So, we can use this? $$\text{sup}_{j=1,2,\dots}|\xi_j|\le|\xi|_p\le\sqrt[p]{n}\cdot \text{sup}|\xi_j|$$

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn I don't know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The $ l^{\infty} $-norm is equal to the limit of the $ l^{p} $-norms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms)

Comment: @MoisheKohan I guess so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant to say is that, just for an alternative approach, if there is some $|\xi_j|\not = 0$ , otherwise it follows immediately,
Let $|\xi_k|=\sup|\xi_j|$ we have,
$$1\le \left(\dfrac{|\xi_1|^p}{|\xi_k|^p}+\dfrac{|\xi_2|^p}{|\xi_k|^p}+\dots+1+\dots+\dfrac{|\xi_n|^p}{|\xi_k|^p}\right)^{1/p}\le \left(1+1+\dots 1\right)^{1/p}=n^{1/p}$$
Then by taking $\displaystyle \lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}$ and sandwich theorem, we obtain the result $\Box$