# Find $L=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n+z^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit following:

$$L=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n+z^n}$$

With $x,\: y\: z\in R$

P.S

I think this limit result is $L=max\left\{x,\: y\: z \right\}$. But i'm not find it, so expect people to help me find out the results by some solution

Extend this limit:

$$S=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{i}^{m}a_{i}}$$ with $a_i\in R,\: i=1,\: m$

Comment: Minimum? Looks like it is the one with the maximum absolute value.

Comment: In addition to Aryabhata's comment, if $x,y,z$ are negative, then the limit does not exist.

Comment: For reference: the thing you are describing is called the **infinity norm** (that is, the limit of the $p$-norms as $p \to \infty$). As the answers below might suggest, it is also called the "maximum norm".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80340/convergence-of-sqrtnxnyn-for-x-y-0?s=1|145.5010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The $ l^{\infty} $-norm is equal to the limit of the $ l^{p} $-norms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms)

Answer (score 15):

Put $M = \max(x,y,z).$  Then you have $M^n \le x^n + y^n + z^n \le 3M^n$.  Take $n$th roots to ge
$$M \le \root{n}\of{x^n + y^n + z^n} \le 3^{1/n}M.$$
Let $n\to \infty$ and see your limit is $M$.

Comment: I am assuming these constants are nonnegative to avoid negative root issues.

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be the max over all terms.

Think of the term which will start dominating the sum when n becomes arbitrarily large ...