# Find the limit of $a_n = \sqrt[n]{b^n + c^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Hard question I am not sure about,

Proof this sequence convergent and find its limit.
$$ a_n = \sqrt[n]{b^n + c^n} $$
$$ b,c \ge 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b=0$, $c=0$ or $b=c$ it is easy. Assume $0<b<c$. Then
$$
a_n=c\,\sqrt[n]{1+\Bigl(\frac{b}{c}\Bigr)^n}.
$$
Since $b/c<1$...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

General of limit: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^n}=\max\left\{ a_i,\: i=1,n \right\}$$

Proof in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582669/find-l-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtnxnynzn)