# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \infty} (3^x+7^x)^{1/x}$

Tags: limits

The question is to evaluate $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (3^x+7^x)^{1/x}$$

I tried evaluating the limit as $exp(\lim_{x\to \infty} (3^x+7^x-1)(1/x))$.I couldn't proceed after this.Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is that$\  \lim_{n \to \infty} (3^n+7^n)^{1/n}$ ?

Comment: @CTSnake sorry that was a typo.

Comment: This was asked tons of times already.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80340/convergence-of-sqrtnxnyn-for-x-y-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) and its related posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

You're on the right track - almost.

If you wanted to keep going the way you are consider,

$$e^{lim_{x \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{ln(3^x + 7^x)}{x}\bigg)}$$

Next, you can apply logarithm laws again, and then l'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 6):

$7 = (7^x)^{1/x} \le (3^x+7^x)^{1/x} \le (7^x+7^x)^{1/x} = 2^{1/x}7$, so the limit is $7$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, $7 < (3^x+7^x)^{1/x} = 7((\frac{3}{7})^x + 1)^{1/x} < 7(2)^{1/x} \rightarrow 7$ when $x\to \infty$.