# Evalute $\lim\sup a_n=\left[1-(-2)^n\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate the limit $$\lim\sup\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$
$$a_n=\left[1-(-2)^n\right]$$.
What I did here is notice that this sequence can be written as the following:$$ a_{2n+1}=3$$ $$a_{2n}=1$$

From here it is really clear that the $\lim\sup a_n=3$, but this is a wrong answer, the correct answer is $2$.

I do not understand what is wrong in my assumptions

Comment: Why do you say that $a_2=1$? Clearly, $a_2=1-(-2)^2=-3$.

Comment: How did you arrive at those values for $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question [$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x^n+y^n},\ x,y> 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80340/721644)? In your case, you just choose $n$ to be odd in order to have $\sqrt[n]{1-(-2)^n}=\sqrt[n]{1+2^n}$.

Comment: For the calculation with logarithm, you can use squeeze lemma: $e^{\frac{\log (2^n +1)}{n}}<E_n< e^{\frac{\log (2^n-1)}{n}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computations are false. I am guessing that you confused $(-2)^n$ with $2 \times(-1)^n$.

The answer is $2$ indeed :

You can check that $|a_n| = 2^n + e_n$, where $(e_n)$ is bounded. Thus, $|a_n|^{\frac1n} = \exp(\frac1n\ln (2^n + e_n)) = \exp\left(\frac{\ln(2^n)+\ln\left(1+\frac{e_n}{2^n}\right)}n\right)\to 2$.

Comment: Indeed, it does not. I am guessing that this is the mistake the OP made.

Comment: By $|a_n|$, I mean the modulus of $a_n$. It is not hard to see that $a_n$ alternates signs. But its modulus is roughly $2^n$

Answer (score 1):

You're computing the values wrongly:
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
1-2^n & \text{$n$ even} \\[6px]
1+2^n & \text{$n$ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus
$$
b_n=\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\begin{cases}
\sqrt[n]{2^n-1} & \text{$n$ even} \\[6px]
\sqrt[n]{2^n+1} & \text{$n$ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus you actually have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=2
$$
in particular the superior limit is $2$. It's not difficult to show that if the even and the odd terms of a sequence converge to the same limit, then also the whole sequence converges to that limit. In this case it's even simpler:
$$
b_n=2\sqrt[n]{1-\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As we are looking for $\lim\sup\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, then may by most  easy is to consider sub sequence $\sqrt[2n+1]{|a_{2n+1}|} =\sqrt[2n+1]{2^{2n+1}+1 }=2 \cdot \sqrt[2n+1]{1+\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}}$ and then show $\lim_{}\sqrt[2n+1]{1+\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}}=1$:
$$1<\sqrt[2n+1]{1+\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}}<\sqrt[n]{2} \to 1$$
For even sub sequense we have $\sqrt[2n]{|a_{2n}|}=\sqrt[2n]{2^{2n}-1}=2 \cdot \sqrt[2n]{1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}} \to2$

Comment: This shows the limsup is at least $2$, right ?

Comment: It can be say so, but taking in view, that other sub sequence is less and have same limit, then comes verdict.

Comment: Yes ! But this argument is needed for a correct proof.

Comment: @FiMePr. That even sub sequense is less - it is not obvious?