# Evaluating $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n + 6^n)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, infinity

I'm completely stuck on how I would go about solving this problem. I'm not sure if I need to use e or ln. Could someone give hints on how I would go about solving this problem?

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n
 + 6^n)^{1/n}$$

Comment: Should the limit be taken over $n$ or $x$?

Comment: Oops, yes! Let me fix that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80340/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/80340

Comment: basic problem with many similar questions

Comment: Your informal instinct, that will guide you to the right answer, should be that as $~n \to \infty,~$ the term $~6^n~$ will **dwarf** the term $~2^n,~$ (informally) making the $~2^n~$ term irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

We may transform the above expression and utilize $e=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n$.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2^n+6^n)^\frac{1}{n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(6^n)^\frac{1}{n}(1+\frac{1}{3^n})^\frac{1}{n}$$
$$=6\lim_{n,3^n\rightarrow\infty}[(1+\frac{1}{3^n})^{3^n}]^\frac{n}{3^n}$$
$$=6\lim_{3^n\rightarrow\infty}[(1+\frac{1}{3^n})^{3^n}]^{\lim_{n,3^n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{3^n}}$$
$$=6e^0=6$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a^n + b^n)^{1/n}
 $
where
$0 < a < b$.

Let
$f(n)
 =(a^n + b^n)^{1/n}
 $.

Then
$f(n)
 \gt(b^n)^{1/n}
 =b$.

Also

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=(a^n + b^n)^{1/n}\\
&=b(1+(a/b)^n)^{1/n}\\
&=b(1+r^n)^{1/n}
\qquad r=a/b < 1\\
\end{array}
$

If
$(1+r^n)^{1/n}
=1+h$
then
$1+r^n
=(1+h)^n
\ge 1+hn
$
by Bernoulli's inequality
so
$r^n \gt hn
$
or
$h \lt \dfrac{r^n}{n}
$.

Rearranging,
$(1+r^n/n)^n
\ge 1+r^n
$
so
$1+r^n/n
\ge (1+r^n)^{1/n}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=b(1+r^n)^{1/n}\\
&\le b(1+r^n/n)\\
&= b+br^n\\
\end{array}
$

so
$b
\le (a^n + b^n)^{1/n}
\le b+b(a/b)^n/n
$.

Since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} b(a/b)^n/n
=0$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a^n + b^n)^{1/n}
=b$.